# Flutter GetX Theme Mode Issue

Tags: flutter, dart, themes, flutter-getx, mode

I am currently working on an application where I have implemented the dark mode. It's all working good when I switch it from light mode to dark mode. The problem starts when I switch back from dark mode to light mode. All the primary color and theme configurations I have added in the app they just get lost.

This is the code from my app start:

```
class TradeWixApp extends StatelessWidget {
  bool darkMode;
  TradeWixApp({Key? key, required this.darkMode}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      translations: Languages(),
      locale: Locale('en'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          titleMedium: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
          bodyMedium: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
        ),
        shadowColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 37, 36, 36),
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
          )),
          color: Color.fromARGB(200, 174, 242, 135),
          elevation: 0,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        primaryColor: Color.fromARGB(200, 174, 242, 135),
        elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.black,
            elevation: 0,
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
          ),
        ),
        textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.grey),
        ),
      ),
      themeMode: darkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
      theme: ThemeData(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
            )),
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 174, 242, 135),
            elevation: 0,
            foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          ),
          primaryColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 174, 242, 135),
          elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.black,
              elevation: 0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            ),
          ),
          textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.grey),
          )),
      home: const SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

and the code where I am switching the dark mode is:

```
Obx(() {
                  return ListTile(
                      title: Text('Dark Mode'.tr),
                      trailing: Switch(
                        value: darkMode.value,
                        onChanged: (value) async {
                          darkMode.value = value;

                          Get.changeTheme(
                              !value ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark());
                          Get.changeThemeMode(
                              !value ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark);
                          Get.reloadAll();
                          final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                          await prefs.setBool('darkMode', value);
                        },
                      ));
                })
```

This is the light before switching
[image: This is the light before switching]

This is the dark mode
[image: This is the dark mode]
This is the light mode after switching
[image: This is the light mode after switching]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why your using `Get.changeTheme` in your piece of code, you have set a `theme`, and `darkTheme` on your `GetMaterialApp`, so to toggle between them, you will need simply to call `Get.changeThemeMode`, but this:

```
Get.changeTheme( !value ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark());
```

The `ThemeData.dark()` and `ThemeData.light()` are new whole themes, I guess your goal is to toggle between light mode and dark mode, not to set a theme between a list of themes for example. so when you call `Get.changeTheme()`, you reset your app themes to the default light a dark ones ( which gives you the behavior that your themes are reset )

Answer (score 3):

**Try to use**

```
Get.changeThemeMode(ThemeMode.light);
```

**instead of**

```
 Get.changeTheme(ThemeData.light());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
```

to your GetMaterialApp.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be late but I hope it helps others facing theming related issue.

If I understand correctly you want your app to keep the colors you defined for each mode (Dark / Light) if you want to do so you need to define your colors in your ThemeData, a great thing I learned in one of my projects experimenting with Material 3 in Flutter (it also works with Material 2, never used it with Material 2 though).

#### TL;DR : You need to define your themes and define colors for each theme separately.

### Long Answer

this way you can add as many themes as you want to your app with the ability to edit the colors anytime and see them reflected through all your app widgets.
Note that you won't have to give your widgets a color/backgroundColor property anymore as the colors are inferred from this file, but you can always use those properties if you have a certain case where the defined theme doesn't suit your needs with some specific widgets.

This code snippet is my whole theme file where I have two themes light and dark with a custom font and defined colors I copied from my Figma design of the app.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppTheme {
  static const darkTheme = ColorScheme.dark(
    primary: Color(0xFFF8D028),
    onPrimary: Color(0xFF333333),
    primaryContainer: Color(0xFFD0C000),
    onPrimaryContainer: Color(0xFF333333),
    secondary: Color(0xFF3B9DFF),
    onSecondary: Color(0xFFF3F3F3),
    secondaryContainer: Color(0xFFF0A000),
    onSecondaryContainer: Color(0xFF333333),
    error: Colors.redAccent,
    onError: Colors.red,
    errorContainer: Colors.redAccent,
    onErrorContainer: Color(0xFFF9DEDC),
    outline: Color(0xFF938F99),
    background: Color(0xFF333333),
    onBackground: Color(0xFFF3F3F3),
    surface: Color(0xFF333333),
    onSurface: Color(0xFFF3F3F3),
    surfaceVariant: Color(0xFF49454F),
    onSurfaceVariant: Color(0xFFCAC4D0),
  );

  static ColorScheme lightTheme = ColorScheme.light(
    primary: const Color(0xFFF8D028),
    onPrimary: const Color(0xFF333333),
    primaryContainer: const Color(0xFFFDD943),
    onPrimaryContainer: const Color(0xFF333333),
    secondary: const Color(0xFF3B9DFF),
    onSecondary: const Color(0xFFF3F3F3),
    secondaryContainer: Colors.amber.shade700,
    onSecondaryContainer: const Color(0xFF333333),
    error: Colors.redAccent,
    onError: Colors.red,
    errorContainer: Colors.redAccent,
    onErrorContainer: const Color(0xFFF9DEDC),
    outline: const Color(0xFF6F6D73),
    background: const Color(0xFFF3F3F3),
    onBackground: const Color(0xFF333333),
    surface: const Color(0xFFFDCC34),
    onSurface: const Color(0xFF333333),
    surfaceVariant: const Color(0xFF57545B),
    onSurfaceVariant: const Color(0xFF757575),
  );

  static final light = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    colorScheme: lightTheme,
  );
  static final dark = ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    colorScheme: darkTheme,
  );
}
```

And here is my ThemeController file using GetX.
Note : I'm using the [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) package to persist my theme state when the app restarts and default to a value of false if it's my first time running the app.

```dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'app_theme.dart';

class ThemeController extends GetxController {
  final box = GetStorage();

  RxBool isDarkMode = false.obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    isDarkMode.value = box.read('isDarkMode') ?? false;
  }

  void toggleTheme() {
    isDarkMode.value = !isDarkMode.value;
    Get.changeTheme(
      isDarkMode.value ? MyFeedbackTheme.dark : MyFeedbackTheme.light,
    );
    box.write('isDarkMode', isDarkMode.value);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to incorporate this with your MaterialApp or GetMaterialApp as our logic is still not operational until we do so.

main.dart

```dart
// rest of code
return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'App Name',
      theme: AppTheme.light,
      darkTheme: AppTheme.dark,
      themeMode: Get.find<ThemeController>().isDarkMode.value
          ? ThemeMode.dark
          : ThemeMode.light,
      home: const WelcomeScreen(),
    );
// rest of code
```

With this your theme switching logic is complete, all you have to do is put it to use using a widget of your choice, in my case I used a Switch widget with GetX Obx just like you did

This is the code snippet for that

```dart
// rest of code
ListTile(
                title: Text("Theme".tr),
                trailing: Obx(
                  () => Switch(
                    value: themeController.isDarkMode.value,
                    onChanged: (value) => themeController.toggleTheme(),
                    activeTrackColor: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                    activeColor: kPrimaryColor,
                    inactiveThumbColor: kPrimaryColor,
                    thumbIcon: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Icon?>(
                      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                        if (states.contains(MaterialState.selected)) {
                          return const Icon(Icons.brightness_2);
                        }
                        return null; // other states will use default thumbIcon.
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
// rest of code
```

This is how the switch looks like so that you don't have to try the code if you don't like it

Dark Mode State

[image]

Light Mode State

[image]

## Last Note

The files I shared (the one containing AppTheme class, and the one containing the ThemeController) stay the same in every app, you only change your color palette and you're ready to go.

#### **But** !!

I still haven't experimented with these options on default Material 2 so I don't know if it'll work for everyone and don't just change your app from M2 to M3 in the middle of development as it can mess up the look of your app. I only advise others to use this method if you're just starting a fresh app. But if you're ready to go through the trouble of fixing the issues caused by the switch from M2 to M3 mid development, I believe this method will save you time and effort significantly especially if your app uses >= 2 themes.

Hope this helps :)